# Update type of trigger is not working in Zapier

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I am trying to create a trigger (Poll based) in Zapier app/integration which should run the zap when an existing item will be updated.

API response contains an array like this:

```
[
  { id: 1, title: 'AWS', time: '2021-12-03T11:41:13.615Z', modTime: '2021-12-03T11:41:13.615Z' },
  { id: 2, title: 'GCP', time: '2021-12-03T11:41:13.615Z', modTime: '2021-12-03T11:46:13.615Z' },
]
```

Now, as per the [doc](https://platform.zapier.com/docs/triggers), if an item will contain `id` and `updated_at` key then it should work if same record will be updated with last modified timestamp field.

> To make an update trigger, use an API endpoint that lists all items, both new and updated, or alternately an endpoint that lists only updated items. Zapier needs a composite id field that changes whenever the item is updated (ideally z.hash('md5', item.id + item.updated_at)), so subsequent updates aren’t be filtered out by Zapier’s deduper.

For that, I created a new key `updated_at` and copied the value of `modTime` key. But this trigger is **working only for new records** and not for any update in existing record. Am I missing something ? I can make id every time new like this `{ id: rec.id + ':' + rec.modTime ... }` but it will run for new records as well which I don't want.
Here is my code:

```
// import statements

const listData = async (z) => {
  const records = await getTaskList(z);
  return records.map((rec) => ({
      ...rec,
      updated_at: rec.modTime
  }));
};


export default {
  display: {
    description: 'Triggers when a task will be updated.',
    label: 'Task Updated',
  },
  key: 'task_updated',
  noun: 'Updated Task',
  operation: {
    outputFields: outFields,
    perform: listData,
    sample: getSampleData(),
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Great question! The Zapier deduper *only* cares about the field named `id`. That's why your solution of only adding a key only works for new items- the deuper doesn't look at `updated_at` at all and is working as intended (new items only). From those docs:

> Zapier needs a composite id field **that changes whenever the item is updated**

So your second approach is correct. The `id` field should be a combination of the original `id` and the `updated_field`. This will trigger for all new *and* updated objects.

Filtering out new objects depends on the API you're sourcing data from. You can do a `.filter` before your `.map`, but will need a way to identify new (not updated) objects. Shot in the dark, but if `time` is the created date and `modTime` is the updated date, you could filter to only return objects where `time !== modTime`. But, this may not be the case.

Ultimately, whatever you reeturn from `listData` will get send to the deduper and triggered on if that zap hasn't seen that `id` before.

Hope that clears it up!